# How to serialize a large object, zip it and upload to Azure Storage Blob in efficient way

Tags: azure, stream, azure-blob-storage

Is there an efficient way to serialize a large object in `C#` (using JSON.Net or other library) > `Zip` it and upload this to Azure Storage Blob.

Performing the operation step by step without streams leads to `OutOfMemory Exception` in the first step itself:

1. Serialize the data model to string using JSON.Net
2. Zip this string data to byte array
3. Using Azure Blob Storage `UploadText` method to upload this to Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: so you have an exception while serializing the object ?

Comment: @Thomas - yes, however, I have encountered OOM exceptions while Zipping and de-serialization as well if the former passes.

Comment: could oyu share your actual code please ?

Answer (score 0):

Might be just a tad bit late but you can use stream apis without zipping to handle this. Assuming you can get away without zipping:

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;

public async Task WriteAsync<T> (T data, string blobId)
{
    var client = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(blobId);
    await using var ms = await client.OpenWriteAsync(true);
    await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(ms, data);
}
```

You can read more about how I got to this at my [blog](https://basantakharel.com/efficiently-transfer-c-objects-to-from-azure-blob-storage/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, finally I was able to get it done much more efficiently by writing a serialiser-deserialiser pair ourself which would serialize the data to byte[] and there after push the data to blob. The written data was much smaller in size and both CPU usage & disk IO went very low. It's been a while but for very large objects IIRC it was ~300x efficient.